# В чем подвох(ifstream)?

Tags: c++, ascii, поток-ввода

Почему-то поток ввода не дает знаки пробелов/перехода на новую строку.
Фрагмент кода:

```
in_f.seekg (0, in_f.end);
    int end_f = in_f.tellg();
    in_f.seekg (0, in_f.beg);
    int current = 0;
    while (!in_f.eof() && ((end_f - current) >= SIZE_OF_BLOCK * SIZE_OF_BLOCK)){
      for (int i = 0; i < SIZE_OF_BLOCK; i++){
           for (int j = 0; j < SIZE_OF_BLOCK; j++){
               in_f >> arr_blocks[i][j];
           }
           current = in_f.tellg();
      }
```

В массиве оказываются только буквы. Как мне добавить пробелы и переход на новую строку?
З.Ы. 
Такой маленький подвопрос: Можно ли как нибудь проверять, сколько символов осталось непрочитанными, другим спосбом, т.е. не таким как у меня, т.к. мне эта конструкция кажется монструозной.

Comment: Нужно после открытия потока один раз сделать `in_f >> std::noskipws;`, тогда пробелы пропускаться не будут.

Comment: Забыл добавить, что массив arr_blocks хранит unsigned char

Comment: Если Вам нужны просто все символы, то используйте не функции потока (которые умеют преобразовывать символы в `int, float` и другие преобразования), а функции буфера (`std::streambuf`, получается функцией потока `rdbuf()`   ), может быть даже и быстрее будет...

Answer (score 0):

Кроме указания `std::noskipws` можно прочитать весь файл в `std::string` так (а после уже обрабатывать строку вместе с вайтспейсом):

```
std::string read(std::ifstream& in) {
    std::stringstream sin;
    sin << in.rdbuf();
    return sin.str();
}
```

Comment: На всякий случай отмечу, что из std::ifstream in  строка получается "в один оператор", а именно `std::string s(
    std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(in), (std::istreambuf_iterator<char>()));`

Answer (score 0):

Нужно просто включить бинарный режим для чтения. Вы не показываете полный код, так-что пока такой намёк:

```
open ("filename",ios_base::openmode mode = ios_base::in | ios_base::binary);
```

Comment: ЕМНИП, это не поможет. `noskipws` нужен даже для двоичных файлов.